# Why won't this create the desired affect of making this a background image in nextJS 13 using Tailwindcss?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, web-frontend

Just as the title states. I'm struggling with how to make this achieve the desired effect.

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

import heroBackground from "../public/hero-background.png";

const Hero = () => {
    return (
        <div className='relative min-h-content max-w-[1920px] '>
            <Image
                src={heroBackground}
                alt='Hero Background'
                className='absolute top-0 left-0'
            />
            <div className='p-24'>
                <h1 className='absolute text-4xl font-bold text-black'>HERO TEXT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Hero;
```

[What the code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvyce.png)

I've tried everything I can think of, and looked up many solutions. However, none of them seem to work for me. When I previously tried to achieve this I somehow with the help of some online tools came up with this.

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const Backdrop = ({ children, title, backgroundImg }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {backgroundImg || title ? (
                <div className='relative flex items-center min-h-content bg-fixed bg-cover'>
                    <Image
                        src={backgroundImg}
                        alt={backgroundImg}
                        className='z-[-1] min-h-[50px]'
                    />
                    <h1 className='absolute top-[35%] left-[10%] w-[60%]'>{title}</h1>
                    <div className='absolute'>{children}</div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>{children}</div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Backdrop;
```

There has to be something easier and less complex that this to achieve a backdrop image effect.

Answer (score 0):

use `background-image` instead of position relative and absolute

Also, if you're using NextJS, you should refer `public/` as your root web directory, so as example:

`../public/hero-background.png` should just be `hero-background.png`

```js
const Hero = () => {
    return (
        // consider having a min-w and min-h value too if u want to see the whole image
        // you should not need relative and absolute anymore
        <div className='min-h-content max-w-[1920px] bg-[url("hero-background.png")]'>
            <div className='p-24'> 
                <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold text-black'>HERO TEXT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

[tailwindcss reference here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I have tried also and does not seem to work either. I have tried different variations in the URL like: "../public/hero-background.png", and "/hero-background.png" as well as what you recommended, but none seem to work. Is there some other way that I need to achieve this in NextJS other than what you mentioned?